# Xamarin forms: Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package

Getting below error in my visual studio.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.1 directly to project MyProject.Android to resolve this issue. 
>    MyProject.Android -> MyProject -> Xamarin.Essentials 1.2.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 28.0.0.1) 
>    MyProject.Android -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2.1).

**I tried to install the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.1` to my android project. It also ended up with another error.**

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 28.0.0.1 directly to project MyProject.Android to resolve this issue. 
>    MyProject.Android -> MyProject -> Xamarin.Essentials 1.2.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (>= 28.0.0.1) 
>    MyProject.Android -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (= 27.0.2.1).

**So I tried to install the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 28.0.0.1` but it again redirects me to the first error.** How can I fix this error, because of this error I can't add new Nuget packages to my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to manually updating your android project .csproj file and specify version of Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.

> Something like below and save the file...Visual Studio will update the
>   specified version

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="28.0.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="28.0.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="28.0.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="28.0.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="28.0.0.1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case
i have also updated Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat

```
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat">
      <Version>28.0.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

thats work for me